# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException after formatting BigDecimal

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal, decimalformat

We are getting the following error while attempting to retrieve the dollar amount without the cents:

```
Caused by java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException length=6; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
```

Here is the code:

```
public static String findDollarAmount(@Nullable BigDecimal fullAmount) {
    if (fullAmount == null || fullAmount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
        return "0";
    }

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00;-#,##0.00");

    //This value is returned as some string value that doesn't contain a '.'
    String amountStr = df.format(fullAmount);

    //The crash happens on this line
    return amountStr.substring(0, amountStr.indexOf('.'));
}
```

We are not able to print out the values in production and we aren't able to recreated this scenario during testing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question I have is: why not format to what you need instead of taking a substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be your application **Locale**.
If the application's Locale has as its currency representation the decimal separator "," as in PT-BR (R$ 1.000,00) will cause exception when performing.
Another hand, sample , the Locale being set to **US** Locale.setDefault(Locale.US) will have decimal separator "." like $1,000.00 and no problem.

Comment: Thank you.  We do use different Locales in the app.  I'll check this out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your format is wrong, in a simulation it seems to return something like "10,00" and you are instead trying to find a dot ".".
Check it out by inserting a `System.out.println(amountStr);` just before the second return and you will be able to see what's the String's formatting.
Just like this:

```
10,00

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 5
```

Comment: Although true, it doesn't explain why the decimal point is a `,` comma, not a `.` period, since the format string has `.` period. *(already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58121102/5221149))*

Answer (score -1):

Could be related to this fact about the Java .substring method:

> The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex – 1 [Found here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-substring-method-example/)

Based off of this, you may need to do something like...

`return amountStr.substring(0, amountStr.indexOf('.') - 1);`

Comment: The problem is that `indexOf` returned -1, and `substring(0, -1)` is invalid. Subtracting 1 doesn't fix anything, because `substring(0, -2)` is also invalid.